# Neo4j Server doesn't connect to embedded database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I'm trying to get a Neo4j server connected to a database embedded in a Rails project. I'm following this guide: https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j%3A%3Aha-cluster The only thing different, I think, is that I'm using the 1.9.7 Neo4j community server. I am able to start the rails server and the rails console, and both work simultaneously. I can start the standalone server just fine, but I can only see the root node in the UI.

I tried to point the standalone server to one of the two embedded databases, but the server then updates the database such that the Rails application doesn't start anymore.

Please let me know if you need more specifics.

Any hints are welcome. Thanks.

Here's the standalone server's neo4j.properties

```
    ha.server_id=3
    ha.initial_hosts=localhost:5001,localhost:5002,localhost:5003
    ha.server=localhost:6003
    ha.cluster_server=localhost:5003
    ha.pull_interval=1
    allow_store_upgrade=false
    keep_logical_logs=true
```

Here's the standalone server's neo4j-server.properties

```
    org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db
    org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
    org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
    org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true
    org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473
    org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert
    org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key
    org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore
    org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location=data/rrd
    org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/
    org.neo4j.server.webadmin.management.uri=/db/manage/
    org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=conf/neo4j.properties
    org.neo4j.server.manage.console_engines=gremlin, shell
    org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=false
    org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

These are the Noe4j and Rails related gems included in my Gemfile:

```
    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
    gem 'neo4j', '>= 2.2.3'
    gem 'neo4j-community', '1.9'
    gem 'neo4j-advanced', '1.9'
    gem 'neo4j-enterprise', '1.9'
```

In config/application.rb I added:

```
   require "neo4j/rails/ha_console/railtie" if Rails.env.development?
   config.neo4j.storage_path = "#{config.root}/db/neo4j-#{Rails.env}" unless Rails.env.development?
```

When I start the rails server:

```
   Config HA cluster, ha.server_id: 1, db: /Users/rene_user/Code/neo_pedigree/db/ha_neo_1
   => Booting WEBrick
   => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
   => Call with -d to detach
   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
   [2014-05-31 00:25:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
   [2014-05-31 00:25:34] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-12-06) [java]
   [2014-05-31 00:25:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=998 port=3000
   starting Neo4j in HA mode, machine id: 1 at localhost:6001 db /Users/rene_user/Code/neo_pedigree/db/ha_neo_1
```

Starting rails console:

```
    Config HA cluster, ha.server_id: 1, db: /Users/rene_user/Code/neo_pedigree/db/ha_neo_1
    Re-Config HA cluster, ha.server_id: 2, db: /Users/rene_user/Code/neo_pedigree/db/ha_neo_2
    Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
    irb(main):001:0> Dog.all.count
    starting Neo4j in HA mode, machine id: 2 at localhost:6002 db /Users/rene_user/Code/neo_pedigree/db/ha_neo_2
    => 3
```

Starting the standalone neo4j server:

```
    Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC - Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
    Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
    HA instance started in process [39548]. Will be operational once connected to peers. See /Users/rene_user/Code/neo4j_server/data/log/console.log for current status.
```

Here's the standalone server's log from the point of starting the server:

```
    2014-05-29 16:45:53.169+0000 INFO  [API] Remote interface ready and available at [http://localhost:7474/]
    20:52:19.925 [main] INFO  org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer - Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
    Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
    2014-05-31 18:52:23.361+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
    2014-05-31 18:52:23.422+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 20 threads available
    2014-05-31 18:52:23.991+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.543+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted discovery module at [/]
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.646+0000 INFO  [API] Loaded server plugin "CypherPlugin"
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.649+0000 INFO  [API]   GraphDatabaseService.execute_query: execute a query
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.650+0000 INFO  [API] Loaded server plugin "GremlinPlugin"
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.650+0000 INFO  [API]   GraphDatabaseService.execute_script: execute a Gremlin script with 'g' set to the Neo4jGraph and 'results' containing the results. Only results of one object type is supported.
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.651+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at [/db/data/]
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.658+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted management API at [/db/manage/]
    2014-05-31 18:52:25.828+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted webadmin at [/webadmin]
    2014-05-31 20:52:26.004:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
    2014-05-31 18:52:26.069+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
    2014-05-31 20:52:26.191:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
    2014-05-31 20:52:26.434:INFO::NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
    2014-05-31 20:52:29.374:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:7474
    2014-05-31 20:52:30.566:INFO::Started SslSocketConnector@localhost:7473
    2014-05-31 18:52:30.567+0000 INFO  [API] Remote interface ready and available at [http://localhost:7474/]
```

Comment: Please share your full config for both servers (config-files + what you pass to the embedded-db constructor), remember you need 3 instances to form a cluster (add an arbiter).

Comment: after trying with 3 instances, please make the log-files of all available somewhere (graph.db/messages.log).